# Extremely clever URL system (how to make advance SEO urls)

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I am building an intensive web application and currently all my URLs at the moment are in `page.php?action=string` format. Don't worry, we have a fall back plan to change all pages quickly to the SEO URLs via a config file.

I want to know two things. What script is running this site:

http://lookbook.nu/ (also http://stackoverflow.com)

If you just look at it, hover over areas, crazy ajax calls, so many subdomain calls, so many clean URLs. What would be the best approach to do this - is this a RoR thing? All the URLs are so clean and structured. It really impressed me.

I am not wishing for a htaccess solution as I am using nginx.

Comment: You could run a website using a couple rocks if there was some way to interface the rocks with the web. As your question deals with opinion and not a concrete problem, it's not a good fit for this site and will be closed.

Comment: I am not asking for opinion. I asked what script lookbook.nu uses - is RoR generating all those clean URLS, topic/343/create/new/post and topic/343/create/new/comment - htaccess and apache would be bonkers.

Comment: "What would be the best approach to do this". That's opinion.

Comment: *shrug* I feel I managed to find an objective enough answer to his question that it doesn't need to be closed.

Comment: @MarcB Good point. I want to know what software/script they use and a good nginx URL friendly manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StackOverflow actually runs on ASP.NET MVC, but you have URL rewriting built in Apache too if that's your thing. No clue about nginx, though.

Edit: A simple Google search revealed http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule so you're in luck!

Comment: Thank you for this. I marked it one point up. I am sure there must be web devs that make nginx apps like this site. Surely you cannot manage all URLs by hand. How do you know Stackoverflow is ASP.NET - it looks like linux master coders behind the scenes to me...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: On a related note, your fanboi'ish attitude won't help you much in the long run. I'm talking about the "linux master coder" comment.